# How to download and install NFC sample applet on Fudan FM1280 dual interface card?

Tags: applet, nfc, javacard

I have a dual interface `Fudan FM1280` which supports both contact (ISO7816) and contactless (ISO14443) interfaces connected to the same chip card. All I want to do is to install an HCI applet on this card.

To do so, I have used the example code from Simalliance (Mobile Near Field Communication (Mobile NFC) Stepping Stones) named "a Reader Mode Applet based on ToolKit interaction". The source code for that example is as below:

```
package pkgReaderModeApplet;

import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;
import javacard.framework.MultiSelectable;
import uicc.toolkit.ToolkitConstants;
import uicc.toolkit.ToolkitException;
import uicc.toolkit.ToolkitInterface;
import uicc.toolkit.ToolkitRegistry;
import uicc.hci.framework.HCIDevice;
import uicc.hci.framework.HCIMessage;
import uicc.hci.framework.HCIService;
import uicc.hci.services.connectivity.ConnectivityService;
import uicc.hci.services.readermode.ReaderListener;
import uicc.hci.services.readermode.ReaderMessage;
import uicc.hci.services.readermode.ReaderService;

public class ReaderModeApplet extends Applet implements ReaderListener, MultiSelectable, ToolkitConstants, ToolkitInterface {

    private ToolkitRegistry myToolKitReg;
    private HCIService myReaderService;
    private ConnectivityService myConnectivityService;
    
    private ReaderModeApplet() {
        myReaderService = (ReaderService) HCIDevice.getHCIService(HCIDevice.READER_SERVICE_ID);
        myReaderService.register(this);
    }

    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength) throws ISOException {
        new ReaderModeApplet().register();
    }
    
    public void processToolkit(short event) throws ToolkitException {
        switch(event) {
            case EVENT_MENU_SELECTION:
                myReaderService.activateEvent(ReaderListener.EVENT_TARGET_DISCOVERED);
                break;
            case EVENT_EVENT_DOWNLOAD_HCI_CONNECTIVITY:
                myToolKitReg.clearEvent(EVENT_EVENT_DOWNLOAD_HCI_CONNECTIVITY);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void process(APDU arg0) throws ISOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    
    public void onCallback(byte event, HCIMessage myHCIMessage) {
        // First: Reception of Datas
        short offset = myHCIMessage.getReceiveOffset();
        short length = myHCIMessage.getReceiveLength();
        byte[] IncomingBuffer = myHCIMessage.getReceiveBuffer();
        switch(event){
            //Target Discovered !!!
            case ReaderListener.EVENT_TARGET_DISCOVERED:
                //Activation of relevant events
                myReaderService.activateEvent(ReaderListener.EVENT_WRITE_EXCHANGE_DATA_RESPONSE);
                myReaderService.activateEvent(ReaderListener.EVENT_GET_PARAMETER_RESPONSE);
                // Check if status is OK
                if (IncomingBuffer[(short)(offset) ] == ReaderMessage.SINGLE_TARGET_STATUS) {
                    // Copy your Datas into IncomingBuffer
                    // and send the first message
                    // prepareAndSendWriteXchgDataCommand(byte timeout, byte[] data, short offset, short len)
                    ((ReaderMessage)myHCIMessage).prepareAndSendWriteXchgDataCommand((byte) -1, IncomingBuffer, (short)offset, (short)length);
                    // Or retrieves informations on the Target discovered
                    ((ReaderService)myReaderService).getReaderRFType();
                    ((ReaderMessage)myHCIMessage).prepareAndSendGetParameterCommand(ReaderMessage.
                    PARAM_ID_TYPE_B_READER_AFI);
                } else {
                    // If status is equal to MULTIPLE_TARGET_STATUS
                    ((ReaderMessage)myHCIMessage).restartReaderModeProcedure();
                    // Warn the user
                }
            break;
        
        //Response received !!
            case ReaderListener.EVENT_WRITE_EXCHANGE_DATA_RESPONSE:
                //First check if response is a Success
                if(myHCIMessage.getInstruction() == (byte)(HCIMessage.RESP_ANY_OK)) {
                    //Copy your Datas into IncomingBuffer
                    // and send your next message
                    ((ReaderMessage)myHCIMessage).prepareAndSendWriteXchgDataCommand((byte) -1, IncomingBuffer, (short)offset, (short)length);
                    // Or you have all the datas and you want to process them
                    myToolKitReg.setEvent(ToolkitConstants.EVENT_EVENT_DOWNLOAD_HCI_CONNECTIVITY);
                    myConnectivityService = (ConnectivityService)HCIDevice.getHCIService(HCIDevice.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE_ID);
                    myConnectivityService.prepareAndSendConnectivityEvent();
                    myReaderService.deactivateEvent(ReaderListener.EVENT_TARGET_DISCOVERED);
                } else {
                    //Or restart the procedure
                    ((ReaderMessage)myHCIMessage).restartReaderModeProcedure();
                }
            break;
            
            case ReaderListener.EVENT_GET_PARAMETER_RESPONSE:
            default:
            break;
            }
            
    }

    public void deselect(boolean arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public boolean select(boolean arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }



}
```

I am using `Java card 2.2.2`, `hci-api-for-java-card-REL-920` and `uicc-api-for-java-card-REL-13_0` to compile this code (using Eclipse) and it results in the cap file needed to be downloaded on card.

I am using `pyApduTool` to interface card. As I connect to card and try to download this applet on my card, I get an error as below and never get to installing step for the downloaded file.

[image]

This card originally contains few packages as:

[image]

And no applet installed. Now, what is the problem with applet downloading on card?

Comment: I think you need to check the card documentation if all applet requirements are fulfilled

Comment: @PaulBastian Thank you, Paul. Is it just a matter of card support?